# Fastest way to tag Facebook friends who liked and commented on one post of mine

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I have a post with lots of comments and likes from my friends. I want to say “thank you” and tag them all in another post.

What is the fastest way to tag all of them? Manually going one by one is quite tiring. :(